# Ember JS: define is not defined

Tags: ember.js

I recently upgraded my app from Ember 1.3 to Ember 2.4.2. However after deploying it to my production environment with `ember build --env production` I noticed a couple of issues.

The first issue was that each script/stylesheet tag had a `integrity` attribute attached to it which made it impossible to load those resources. After some investigation I decided to just replace the value for those attributes to be empty. This allowed the app to download the resources but I then noticed an error in the console that said `define is not defined` on the minified website.js file that Ember creates. I'm unable to replicate this issue locally because the app runs fine. What steps can I additionally take to investigate this issue? Could this be related to some addon that I have installed, or maybe the SRI integrity attribute that I removed?

Edit: I just tried building and deploying a vanilla app with Ember (e.g. `ember new testApp and ember build --env production` and encountered the same issue. Is there an issue with Ember that I don't know about? I don't think it's my server since I'm able to render a plain index.html just fine.

Comment: Hi, there are lots of things changed in Ember.js from version 1.3 to 2.4. Do you have a public github repo about your project? If you would like to understand more about the new resolver I've just experimented with it here: https://github.com/zoltan-nz/ember-resolver-experiment, and here you can find a detailed tutorial about using ember v2.4 and ember-cli: http://yoember.com

Comment: It's just a small website I host on my raspberry pi, it is found at github.com/uioporqwerty/website. It's not very complicated at all. Just a couple of views and components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use the latest NodeJS (v5.8) and the latest `npm`.
You can update your npm with `npm install -g npm`.
[The best way to install NodeJS](https://yoember.com/nodejs/the-best-way-to-install-node-js/)

I guess, you have the latest ember-cli. You can update it if you are outside of your project:

```
$ cd ~
$ npm install -g ember-cli
```

I just cloned your repository.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/uioporqwerty/website.git
$ cd website
$ npm install && bower install
$ ember server
```

Got the following error:

```
➜  website git:(master) ember s
version: 2.4.2
The Broccoli Plugin: [ConfigLoader] failed with:
Error: Attempting to watch missing directory: config
    at EventEmitter.Watcher_addWatchDir [as addWatchDir] (/Users/szines/projects/temp/website/node_modules/broccoli-sane-watcher/index.js:90:11)
    at /Users/szines/projects/temp/website/node_modules/ember-cli-broccoli/lib/builder.js:95:35
   ...
```

Because of a couple of important files are missing from your ember-cli project, I just run `ember init`

```
$ ember init
```

During this process you see a question. You can check suggested changes with 'd', but it would just remove bootstrap and font-awesome, which is fine, because we will reinstall them with `ember install`.

```
[?] Overwrite bower.json? (Yndh) Y
```

Now we remove all the previous bower and npm package, temp folder and dist folder.

```
$ rm -rf bower_components node_modules tmp dist
$ npm install && bower install
```

Install `ember-bootstrap` and `ember-font-awesome`:

```
$ ember install ember-bootstrap
$ ember install ember-font-awesome
```

Launch the server:

```
$ ember server
```

Your app working like a charm. Open localhost:4200 in your browser.

You can build the production:

```
$ ember build --prod
```

And all the files will be in `/dist` folder.

Or run the production version with the server:

```
$ ember server --prod
```

Enjoy your new Ember! :)

Update:

You can use `ember-cli-update` for updating your Ember app:

```
$ npx ember-cli-update
$ npx ember-cli-update --run-codemods
```

Source: [Update Ember.js app](https://yoember.com/emberjs/how-to-keep-your-ember-js-project-up-to-date/)

Answer (score 2):

Zoltan's answer was very helpful in being a part of the solution to my problem. After fixing my local website according to Zoltan's answer I noticed some issues.

First, there was the following error with Ember-Cli 2.4.2:

`Could not find module ember-data/-private\system\references\record imported from ember-data/-private/system/references`

This issue has been resolved in the master branch of the Github repo for ember-cli but it hasn't made its way to the npm repo. So what I did was uninstall ember-cli with `npm remove -g ember-cli` and then followed the development instructions on the github repo https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli. This fixed that issue.

Additionally, I noticed that my nginx server was not serving js and css files; I tested this by creating a index.html with test.css and test.js and noticed that the server wasn't dishing out those files. Instead of trying to find the issue I noticed my nginx was a bit out of date on my RPI, it was at version 1.6.x, so I thought this would be a good time to update it; I updated it to 1.9.7  by first removing the old version then running this script https://gist.github.com/MattWilcox/402e2e8aa2e1c132ee24. After that I had nginx 1.9.7 but I did somehow have apache2 installed which caused its own headaches with recognizing the default website so I removed it.

Finally, since my settings were overridden I restored /etc/nginx from an rsync backup I have of my pi by just copying over that directory.

Then boom, everything worked. It took a while but everything seems to be working great at https://www.uioporqwerty.com and the qualsys lab report is working fine too https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.uioporqwerty.com so all my settings carried over correctly :)

Glad to have Ember-Cli working correctly.